# How do I calculate discount and add up the totals for records returned - PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'shares' which contain asset_id, , asset_value, member_id, and percent_ownership. I am trying to sum up the value of shares for a specific member. For example: member_id #1 has the following shares:

```
| asset_id  asset_value  member_id  percent_owner
| --------  -----------  ---------  -------------
|    1          300          1           100
| -----------------------------------------------
|    2          300          1            50
| -----------------------------------------------
```

If coded properly, my query should return $450 (100% of 300 + 50% of 300).

I am thinking of having MySQL do the math for each individual record and store it in an array using PHP. PHP will then sum everything up. I am very new to MySQL and PHP so please bear with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT member_id, SUM(asset_value * percent_owner / 100)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY member_id
```

would return all of the member IDs and their share values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Sum(Asset_value * (percent_ower / 100)) From shares Where Member_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (asset_value * percent_owner) / 100 AS shares FROM table;
```

Comment: this would return proportional value for each DB record and NOT the sum of proportional values across ALL assets for each member. Marc B's sql does just that

Comment: And the OP said he wanted to do the summing in PHP "and store it in an array using PHP. PHP will then sum everything up"

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on aggregate queries in MySQL but to get you started you will probably end up with something like

```
SELECT
    member_id,
    [do your maths here]
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    member_id
```

Have a go yourself and if you get stuck post any specific problems you have back here.